# Mule Batch - How to stop auto restart when server restarts?

Tags: mule, esb

The Mule batch is auto restarting when the mule server restarts. Is there any option to flip this behavior on and off?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the trigger of your *Batch* processing? Is it a *Poll* scheduler?

If so, based on your description its method should be *Fixed Frequency Scheduler* not a *Cron Scheduler*. Therefore, set the delay to prevent auto start when Mule server is restarted.

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/_images/poll_scheduler.png

Answer (score 0):

you can use batch reference message processor with HTTP end point. Batch will only trigger when inbound http request is made.

Reference : https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.9/batch-processing#triggering-batch-jobs